# Ensuring data update visibility for other threads using fences

Tags: multithreading, c++11, synchronization, memory-fences

I have two questions - consider two threads, one making changes to shared data and the other operating on the shared data. Both threads acquire a mutex before doing anything with the data.

How can I guarantee that the thread operating on the data always sees the changes done by the first thread? Is a set of acquire/release fences required, or do the threads synchronize implicitly by using a mutex? What if I don't use a mutex (but otherwise ensure exclusive access)?

And: Do fences actually do anything without an interleaved/follow-up atomic operation (like, storing a flag in a atomic_bool, signaling 'ready' or something)?

Here's a use case:

```
void func()
{
    std::atomic_bool quit = false;

    std::vector<float> data(100);
    std::mutex m;

    std::thread one([&]() 
        {
            while (!quit.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m, std::try_to_lock);

                if (lock.owns_lock())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        data[i] = std::rand();
                    }

                    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order::memory_order_release);
                }
            }
        }
    );

    std::thread two([&]() 
        {
            while (!quit.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m, std::try_to_lock);

                if (lock.owns_lock())
                {
                    // guaranteed that any changes from thread one to 'data' is seen after this fence?
                    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order::memory_order_acquire);

                    auto res = std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
                    std::cout << "Accumulated result is: " << res << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    );

    fgetc(stdin);

    quit.store(true);
    one.join();  two.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I guarantee that the thread operating on the data always sees the changes done by the first thread? Is a set of acquire/release fences required, or do the threads synchronize implicitly by using a mutex?

Mutex do all the work. No needs in additional memory fences.

> What if I don't use a mutex (but otherwise ensure exclusive access)?

This is dependent from mechanism, which ensures `exclusive access`. Most mechanisms don't require additional fences for use. [Strictly speaking, **exclusive** access by definition implies corresponded memory ordering.]

Memory fences may be needed when access is actually **concurrent**, but you want to ensure some invariant to be observed, when *other* variables are accessed.

> Do fences actually do anything without an interleaved/follow-up atomic operation (like, storing a flag in a atomic_bool, signaling 'ready' or something)?

Fences are not bounded to atomic operations only. Actually fences are just barriers, which splits **all accesses** (store, load, or both, depending from the type of fence) on two groups: before fence and after it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. As for the last part, I meant whether the fence has any effect/guaranteed behaviour when there's no surrounding atomic operations?

Comment: Okay, so case in point: Thread A writes to some fields of a shared object, and issues a release fence. Thread B issues an acquire fence after thread A has issued the release fence. Thread B will then see all changes done by A, even though no explicit mutex was involved?

Comment: **There is no crossorder between fences**. Only crossorder between shared object accesses has a sence. For things work correctly, **release fence** should be issued **before** writing to share object, **acquire fence** should be issued **after** reading shared object. And reading should return result of writng.

Answer (score 0):

Fence is merely a signal for hardware to make internal cache(s) in sync with main memory. On effect, they are execution barriers - and demand memory synchronization before this barrier can be passed. Hence the name.